# Make a payplan app in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I am developing a custom payment plugin for the PayPlan component. Below is the structure which I made after referring to the URL: https://github.com/readybytes/PayplansCustomApp

firstdata(Folder)

--firstdata.xml

--firsdata.php

--firstdata(folder)

---app

------firstdata.xml

-------firstdata.php

When I install it via the Joomla Extension Manager, it installs successfully, but when I open my plugin, it does not shows any fields, as it is possibly taking the firstdata which is in the root folder not the *firstdata.xml* which resides inside the app folder that contains fields defined in the XML file.

What I'm not able to understand is, do I have to make that kind of structure in order to install the plugin or there is any other way around to make a plugin(app)?

Comment: Did you use that phing script to create your custom plugin?

Comment: Nope i didnot used it

Comment: Ok I don't know these kind of plugins but I would suggest to build your plugin with the help of the phing script just to be sure you didn't make a mistake. What's the content of your xml file in the app folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make an app for payplan component is to see the already made plugin and then modify it according to your needs